# What is the difference between "jobject" & "jclass" in C++ NDK

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build

I did 2 different implementations from tutorials I followed and I noticed the parameters are a little different for each one, 1 parameter is `jclass` and the other is `jobject` I don't use these parameters at all, but I tried experimenting and switching them from `jclass` to `jobject` and `jobject` to `jclass` and I noticed everything still works as expected so I'm not sure what exactly `jobject` and `jinstance` do exactly, also if my method is not using either of these parameters why are they required ? and can someone please provide the correct declaration of these methods in my java class i'm unsure if I did it right

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_pauseSounds(JNIEnv* env, jclass thiz);

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_score(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally,

- if the JNI function arguments have `jclass`, then this JNI function corresponds to the Java side **class method** (the native methods declared **with** "**static**").  `jclass` is a reference to the *current class*.
- if the JNI function arguments have `jobject`, then this JNI function corresponds to the Java side **instance method** (the native methods declared **without** "**static**"). `jobject` is a reference to the *current instance*.

Specifically,

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_pauseSounds(JNIEnv* env, jclass thiz);
```

corresponds to the *static* native method (*class method*) on your Java side, i.e.

```java
package org.cocos2dx.cpp

class AppActivity{
    public static native void pauseSounds();
}
```

While below JNI method

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_cocos2dx_cpp_AppActivity_score(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance);
```

corresponds to the native method (*instance method*) on your Java side, i.e.

```java
package org.cocos2dx.cpp

class AppActivity{
   public native String score();
}
```

> if my method is not using either of these parameters why are they required ?

These parameters are auto generated and will be used by JNI if needed, for example, in the case that you need to call back the Java side *class* methods, you need something like below (`()V"` is the method JNI signature):

```
jmethodID staticMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "pauseSounds", "()V");
```

in the case that you need to call back the Java side *instance* methods, you need something like below(`()Ljava/lang/String;"` is the method JNI signature):

```
env->CallObjectMethod(instance, "score", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation !, how come I don't have to declare static next to JNIEXPORT if the method is declared as static in the java code ?

Comment: You don't need to *declare* static in the JNI part, and the static characteristics can be told by the `jclass` argument and JNI will recognise this method is a class method. Also please note that the term `static` is different on Java and C/C++ semantics.

Comment: do we need a semicolon when we write "extern "C" { };" or should we write it like "extern "C" { }" ???

Comment: Don't need semicolon

Comment: Would you be able to help with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266237/how-do-i-include-a-call-to-make-sure-checksum-matches-apk

Answer (score 1):

In C, all other JNI reference types are defined to be the same as jobject. For example:

```
typedef jobject jclass;
```

In C++, JNI introduces a set of dummy classes to enforce the subtyping relationship. For example:

```
class _jobject {};
class _jclass : public _jobject {};
```

a sample of usage:

```
JNIEnv* env = ...;
// substitute your desired class's specifier for "java/lang/Class"...
jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class"); 
jmethodID mid_getName = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring name = env->CallObjectMethod(cls, mid_getName);
```

[this link goes to oracle documentation of jni for java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) and [this link goes to documentation of jni in java 8 almost the same.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html)

Comment: can you show how the java declaration would look for each method ? im not sure if their suppose to be different for each one

Comment: what im confused about is the jstring method is declared as static in java, but do I have to also declare it as static next to JNIEXPORT OR JNICALL ?

Comment: no, you don't have to declare as static, JNIEXPORT and JNICALL are just decorator with some information JNIEXPORT is define as`  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`  in my installation and `JNICALL __stdcall`,  **__attribute__** is and attribute that is define for some compiler and **__stdcall** is  the calling convention used for the function. This tells the compiler the rules that apply for setting up the stack, pushing arguments and getting a return value.